# Take an id from R with a string

Tags: java, android, xml, android-resources

I have a table with some buttons and TextView (called Row2Col1, Row2Col3, Row2Col4), and I would like to get their id from a string dinamically generated. The code is:

```
String index = "Row" + (currentRow + 2) + "Col1";
    Button buttonTable = (Button) findViewById(getResources()
            .getIdentifier(index, "id", getPackageName()));
    buttonTable.setVisibility(0);

    index = "Row" + (currentRow + 2) + "Col3";
    TextView textViewBrand = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    textViewBrand = (TextView) findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier(
            index, "id", getPackageName()));
    textViewBrand.setText(brand);

    index = "Row" + (currentRow + 2) + "Col4";
    TextView textViewTread = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    textViewTread = (TextView) findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier(
            index, "id", getPackageName()));
    textViewTread.setText(tread);
```

The program crash at the second line, where is the findViewById. Any ideas?

Comment: The posted code doesn't have error?

Comment: The error is "java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.Button", but in this position I have a button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According your error text, you have TextView in xml, but you are trying to cast it to Button in code. Change your code to

```
String index = "Row" + (currentRow + 2) + "Col1";
    TextView buttonTable = (TextView) findViewById(getResources()
            .getIdentifier(index, "id", getPackageName()));
    buttonTable.setVisibility(0);
```

and it will works.